# Python dictionary isn't updating

Tags: python

```
def mergeDict(object):
    dict1 = {}
    for i in range(len(object)):
        dict1.update({'id': object[i].id, 'name': object[i].name, 'age': object[i].age, 'location': object[i].location})
        return dict1
merged_dict = mergeDict(details_sorted)
```

But this doesn't work.

I want to get something like this:

```
{1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'age': '25'; 'location': 'somewhere'},
 2: {'id': 2, 'name': ......}}
```

Comment: I'm a little curious why you need a dictionary of other dictionaries keyed to their sorted integer values.

Comment: dict((x.id, vars(x)) for x in object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to `update` the dict; you just want to insert a value on key `i`. Also, the return goes *after* the for, not in it. Here is a modified version:

```
def mergeDict(object):
    dict1 = {}
    for i in range(len(object)):
        dict1[i] = {'id': object[i].id, 'name': object[i].name, 'age': object[i].age, 'location': object[i].location}
    return dict1
merged_dict = mergeDict(details_sorted)
```

Your `update` version would have updated the `id`, `name`, `age` and `location` keys of `dict1` -- and you don't want that. You want to update the `id` key of `dict1` with another dictionary *containing* the keys `id`, `name`, `age` and `location`.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the return statement is in the for loop, which means it will only ever return the update of the first dict.

Comment: Thanks, that was part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do a bit of experiment.

```
def mergeDict(object):
    dict1 = {}
    dict1.update({'id': 'object[i].id', 'name': 'object[i].name', 'age': 'object[i].age', 'location': 'object[i].location'})
    dict1.update({'id': 'object[j].id', 'name': 'object[j].name', 'age': 'object[j].age', 'location': 'object[j].location'})
    return dict1
merged_dict = mergeDict(None)
print merged_dict
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'object[j].name', 'age': 'object[j].age', 'location': 'object[j].location', 'id': 'object[j].id'}
```

Errors:

> Only last object values are retained as the keys are same for all objects. So the for loop has no effect.

It's like saying

```
x = {}
x['k'] = y
x['k'] = z
```

There is only one key - k and it's latest value is z

Answer (score 1):

One-liner in Python 3.0:

```
merged_dict = {i: dict(id=o.id, name=o.name, age=o.age, location=o.location) 
                  for i, o in enumerate(details_sorted)}
```

If the result keys are consecutive integers, why not a list instead of dict?

```
merged = [ dict(id=o.id, name=o.name, age=o.age, location=o.location) 
                      for i, o in enumerate(details_sorted) ]
```

A list has the added benefit of preserving sort order.